# Github actions bump tags with multiple projects

Tags: github-actions, versioning, cicd

I have a repo with which I deploy multiple instances of the code depending on which part changes.
I want to automate the deployment on github actions with semantic versioning based on labeled pull requests.
e.g. if instance1 should be deployed, it would bump vX.Y.Z-instance1. If instance2 should be deployed, it would bump vX.Y.Z-instance2.

What are the best practices for that on github actions ?